# How to merge subarrays by one key value and push qualifying values into a deeper indexed subarray?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

I am trying to merge the subarrays of a multidimensional array based on the the `hash` value.

My input looks like this:

```
$images_arr = [
    [
        'hash' => '948e980ed2a36d917f1b3026b04e0016',
        'filename' => ['73315_73316_73317_LAKE13437_322.tif'],
        'filepath' => ['_TEST_DATA']
        // and there is more data here
    ],
    [
        'hash' => '948e980ed2a36d917f1b3026b04e0016',
        'filename' => ['73315_73316_73317_LAKE13437_322(1).tif'],
        'filepath' => ['_TEST_DATA/subdirectory']
        // and there is more data here
    ]
];
```

Where one or more `hash` values match, I want to merge the arrays and combine the `filename` subarray values and and the `filepath` subarray values into the first.

Something like this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'hash' => '948e980ed2a36d917f1b3026b04e0016',
    'filename' => 
    array (
      0 => '73315_73316_73317_LAKE13437_322.tif',
      1 => '73315_73316_73317_LAKE13437_322(1).tif',
    ),
    'filepath' => 
    array (
      0 => '_TEST_DATA',
      1 => '_TEST_DATA/subdirectory',
    ),
    // more data here
  ),
)
```

The array will contain thousands of records and I need to be able to combine multiple arrays where only the `hash` values match.

My efforts so far were to use foreach on the array to create a variable to cache the hash value and check against following loops. Then I am able to extract the `filename` or `filepath` where this is the case. Not sure if this the most proficient method though - apologies, I am still a php novice.

My coding attempt:

```
$cache_hash = null;
foreach ($images_arr as $image) {
    $this_hash = $image['hash'];

    if ($cache_hash != $this_hash) {
        $cache_hash = $this_hash;
    } else {

        foreach ($image['filename'] as $filename) {
            //Get filename
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assigning temporary keys to your result array based on each dataset's `hash` value, you can identify if you are storing the first occurrence of the hash, or if you need to push the new values.

When the loop completes, remove the temporary (outer) keys to generate your desired result.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CPQMe))

```
$array = [
    [
        'hash' => '948e980ed2a36d917f1b3026b04e0016',
        'filename' => ['73315_73316_73317_LAKE13437_322.tif'],
        'filepath' => ['_TEST_DATA']
    ],
    [
        'hash' => '948e980ed2a36d917f1b3026b04e0016',
        'filename' => ['73315_73316_73317_LAKE13437_322(1).tif'],
        'filepath' => ['_TEST_DATA/subdirectory']
    ]
];

foreach ($array as $set) {
    if (!isset($result[$set['hash']])) {          // check if 1st occurrence of hash value
        $result[$set['hash']] = $set;             // save whole set
    } else {                                      // not 1st occurrence
        $result[$set['hash']]['filename'][] = $set['filename'][0];  // push filename value into this hash's group
        $result[$set['hash']]['filepath'][] = $set['filepath'][0];  // push filepath value into this hash's group
    }
}

var_export(array_values($result));  // re-index the result array to remove temp keys
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'hash' => '948e980ed2a36d917f1b3026b04e0016',
    'filename' => 
    array (
      0 => '73315_73316_73317_LAKE13437_322.tif',
      1 => '73315_73316_73317_LAKE13437_322(1).tif',
    ),
    'filepath' => 
    array (
      0 => '_TEST_DATA',
      1 => '_TEST_DATA/subdirectory',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you for you help (apologies for not posting my efforts - was on right track but that is very helpful). Will test :)

Comment: Both posted answers will work as desired.  Divyesh's answer doesn't bother to check if the first occurrence so it saves a function call on each iteration, but it overwrites the existing hash value with the same hash value as a result.  Virtually the same.

Comment: This worked perfectly - There are numerous other values in the array and this kept these intact without having to additionally resetting each value in merge

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare array with hash key. Try following.

```
<?php
// Input array set
$input = array(
    array(
        'hash' => '948e980ed2a36d917f1b3026b04e0016',
        'filename' => array('73315_73316_73317_LAKE13437_322.tif'),
        'filepath' => array('_TEST_DATA')
    ),
    array(
        'hash' => '948e980ed2a36d917f1b3026b04e0016',
        'filename' => array('73315_73316_73317_LAKE13437_322(1).tif'),
        'filepath' => array('_TEST_DATA/subdirectory')
    ),
    array(
        'hash' => '948e980ed2a36d917f1b3026b04e0018',
        'filename' => array('73315_73316_73317_LAKE13437_321.tif'),
        'filepath' => array('_TEST_DATA/subdirectory')
    ),
    array(
        'hash' => '948e980ed2a36d917f1b3026b04e0018',
        'filename' => array('73315_73316_73317_LAKE13437_321(1).tif'),
        'filepath' => array('_TEST_DATA/subdirectory')
    ),
);

$mergeArrayWithHash = [];
foreach ($input as $value) {
    $mergeArrayWithHash[$value['hash']]['hash'] = $value['hash'];
    $mergeArrayWithHash[$value['hash']]['filename'][] = $value['filename'][0];
    $mergeArrayWithHash[$value['hash']]['filepath'][] = $value['filepath'][0];
}
// Your Output array
$result = array_values($mergeArrayWithHash);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
exit;
```

Comment: Yeah! But that's fine :)